# Does changing difficulty affect any of the trophies?

Tags: achievements, god-of-war-2018

I have beaten the game on the hard difficulty but now I'd like to put it on normal or easy.

I want the platinum trophy, does changing the difficulty affect trophies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no trophies related to the difficulty in the game.

You can achieve the platinum trophy on any difficulty and change the difficulty at any time with no worries.

Source: I have the platinum trophy.

Comment: Nice source!! haha